# Using while and if function together with a condition change

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to use `python` to conduct a calculation which will `sum the values in a column` only for the time period that a certain condition is met.

However, the summation should begin when the conditions are met `(runstat == 0 and oil >1)`. The summation should then stop at the point when `oil == 0`.

I am new to python so I am not sure how to do this.

I connected the code to a `spreadsheet` for testing purposes but the intent is to connect to live data. I figured a `while loop` in combination with an `if function` might work but I am not winning.

Basically I want to have the code start when `runstat` is zero and oil is higher than 0. It should stop summing the values of oil when the oil row becomes zero and then it should write the data to `a SQL database` (this I will figure out later - for now I just want to see if it can work).

This is what code I have tried so far.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel('TagValues.xlsx')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['oiltag'] = df['oiltag'].astype(float)
df['runstattag'] = df['runstattag'].astype(float)
oil = df['oiltag']
runstat = df['runstattag']


def startup(oil,runstat):
    while oil.all() > 0:
        if oil > 0 and runstat == 0:       
            totaloil = sum(oil.all())
            print(totaloil)
        else:
            return None
    return 

print(startup(oil.all(), runstat.all()))
```

It should sum the values in the column but it is returning: None

Comment: Can you give an example of the data going in (i.e. what's in `TagValues.xlsx`)?  Also are your rows in order - are you effectively looking for all the rows between two points?

Comment: Okay sure, the columns in TagValues basically look like this: 

Timestamp         oiltag    runstattag

2/20/2019 22:39 0.11         0
2/20/2019 22:40 0.21         1

there are about 600 rows.. I want to look at all the rows between the two points where the condition is met. The other things is, the code must only look at the 0 in runstattag initially and not again when it changes because I want to calculate the amount of oil used even after runstat becomes 1. The values look bad when I post them but it's basically columns of time, oil used and runstat 0 or 1.

Comment: Are you wanting to start from the row where `oil > 1` or where `oil > 0`?

Comment: I would like to start where oil > 0 and runstat =0. And then sum all the oil rows until oil = 0.

Comment: Ok then I think my answer should do it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I think that what you want to do is get the subset of rows between the two conditions, then get a sum of those.

**Method:** Slice the dataframe to get the relevant rows and then sum.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel('TagValues.xlsx')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['oiltag'] = df['oiltag'].astype(float)
df['runstattag'] = df['runstattag'].astype(float)

def startup(dframe):
    start_row = dframe[(dframe.oiltag > 0) & (dframe.runstattag == 0)].index[0]
    end_row = dframe[(dframe.oiltag == 0) & (dframe.index > start_row)].index[0]
    subset = dframe[start_row:end_row+1] # +1 because the end slice is non-inclusive
    totaloil = subset.oiltag.sum()
    return totaloil

print(startup(df))
```

This code will raise an error if it can't find a subset of rows which match your criteria. If you need to handle that case, then we could add some exception handling.

**EDIT:** Please note this assumes that your criteria is only expected to occur once per excel. If you have multiple “chunks” that you will want to sum then this will need tweaking.

Comment: Thank you.. I ran the code and I get the following error:

NameError: name 'start' is not defined

Comment: Whoops, that was a mistake in my code. I’ve edited it so try it again now

Comment: I eventually want to connect this code to data coming from a historian. In that case it would constantly be monitoring the tags and then I would want it to write the summed oil value to a SQL database after each run. So I would need to have some way of resetting the variable after it is written to the database.

Comment: Without a full example of how you would be reading in that data it’s difficult to say how you should handle that case. If you’re going to be streaming it effectively row-by-row then you will need a slightly different approach to the one here, where you have the entire data set up front

Comment: I'll have to get back to you on this one as I need to figure out how to connect to the historian's database. Thank you so much for helping thus far..